# Extract Content From Specific Docx Files Using Python-Docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I am using the [Python-Docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library for a project that extracts text, headers, and images from a word document. However, I do not want to extract this from every page of the word document, I only want this content from the first 3 pages. If someone could write an example code for:

1. Load Word document file.
2. Search for any headers, text, or images.
3. Only search for the first 3 pages of the document.
4. Take found headers, text, and images and append them to new document using Python-Docx.